# using vector::erase causes a malloc(): memory corruption (fast) c++

Tags: c++, vector, allocation, erase

I have a Group class which has a vector v_group;
and ofc something to get the size of the vector and to remove a item:

Group class

```
void Group::drawGroup()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < v_group.size(); i++)
    {
       v_group.at(i).draw();
    }
}

void Group::add(Mesh object)
{
    v_group.push_back(object);
}

Mesh &Group::get(int location)
{
    return v_group.at(location);
}

void Group::clear()
{
    v_group.clear();
}

void Group::remove(int location)
{
    v_group.erase(v_group.begin()+(location));
}

bool Group::remove(Mesh object)
{
    return true;
}

int Group::size()
{
   return v_group.size();
}
```

In my other class I'm creating a Group object:

```
in header: `Group *m_group;`

Renderer::Renderer() : m_group(new Group())
{
}

void Renderer::drawGL()
{
   m_group->drawGroup();
}

void Renderer::addObject(float width,float height,string texture_url)
{
    UseableObject uobj(width,height,texture_url);
    m_group->add(uobj);
}

void Renderer::RemoveObject(int index)
{
    m_group->remove(index);
}

void Renderer::move(int objectIndex, float x, float y)
{
    m_group->get(objectIndex).setPosX(x);
    m_group->get(objectIndex).setPosY(y);
}

Group& Renderer::GetGroup()
{
    return *m_group;
}
```

Somewhere else I'll want to erase a object from the initial Group vector using:

```
DropObject::DropObject(Renderer *renderer)
{
    this->renderer = renderer;

    //insert a i (count) into the vector to represent the already Available objects, and continue from there with the DropObjects
    for(int i = 0;i < renderer->getGroupSize();i++)
    {
        yIndex.push_back(10);      //Vector 
        xIndex.push_back(10);      //Vector
    }

}

DropObject::~DropObject()
{

}

void DropObject::Create(int &ENEMY_movePosition, const int &ENEMY_start_height)
{
    renderer->addObject(20,20,"");
    xIndex.push_back(ENEMY_movePosition);
    yIndex.push_back(ENEMY_start_height);//just add index, nothing else cam into my mind right now ._.
    cout << ENEMY_start_height << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < yIndex.size();i++)
    {
        cout << "y vec= " << yIndex[i] << endl;
    }

}

void DropObject::Move(int index)
{
    //current index set to isRemoved = false , because it's still there
    isRemoved = false;

    //x remains the same, y decrease by 1 (->  =-1)
  try
  {
    yIndex[index] -= 2;
    renderer->move(index,xIndex[index],yIndex[index]);

    if(yIndex[index] < -250)
    {
        //renderer->RemoveObject(index);
        renderer->GetGroup().remove(index);
        yIndex.erase(yIndex.begin() + index);
        xIndex.erase(yIndex.begin() + index);

        isRemoved = true;
    }
   }catch(std::out_of_range ex)
    {
        cout << "DropObject move out of range:" << ex.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

which works, but after `xIndex.erase(yIndex.begin() + index);` the programm crashes with a segmentation fault 
or when I'm trying to call the vector from Group again. I get a malloc(): memory corruption (fast)  error.

Maybe after erasing a element, the memory is still allocated for it, and therefore i'g such errors?

anyone can help?

Comment: Maybe, if you can create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us instead?

Comment: Add to your code in post second call of vector from Group.

Comment: Maybe for simplicity, you didn't add any check of the location before erasing, so you might be erasing an out of bound entry which causes this.  Could you adapt your question if this is not the case?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I'm trying to call the vector from Group again"? sscce please!

Comment: If you're messing around with `new` and pointer members, then you probably forgot the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722). Change the type of `m_group` to `Group`, or `std::unique_ptr<Group>` if you really want dynamic allocation for some reason.

Comment: `m_group` is `vector<Mesh>` right? I think the problem is in Mesh which is probably not being copied correctly. `Mesh` is being copied when the vector erase is called, and if `Mesh::~Mesh` or `Mesh::Mesh(const Mesh&)` or `Mesh::operator=(const Mesh&)` are undefined or wrongly defined. Alternatively someone somewhere is retaining a reference to a `Mesh` which no longer exists.

Comment: I won't have access to the code until monday.
Can't try any given solution or post additional code right now, sry

Comment: I've added more code now!

Comment: I'm kinda sure it has to do with the erase

Comment: `xIndex.erase(yIndex.begin() + index);` you are deleting from xIndex using an iterator to element from yIndex.

Comment: omg. i think i went about 100 times through the code and didn't notice this simple mistake....
I'll change to a 2D vector now anyway.
Thanks @Dragos Calin
and everyone who went through the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    yIndex.erase(yIndex.begin() + index);
    xIndex.erase(yIndex.begin() + index);
```

at xIndex.erase() I used yIndex and not xIndex.
Terrible mistake.